# OpenTok CreateSession "Error with request submission"

Tags: opentok

Since 31th July 2018 it doesnt work.

When I tried to create a new session id, the exception return below error:

> "Error with request submission".

```
var Session = OpenTok.CreateSession(mediaMode: MediaMode.ROUTED);
```

I've tried this link as the web developer site indicates, and everything is ok.
https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000046059-Desupporting-TLS-1-0

I'm using .net 4.5.2 and opentok api Version=2.4.6431.26897

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

We disabled support for TLS 1.0 on August 1st which is what your issue looks like. 
Please confirm that you're not using TLS 1.0 on your production environment.

You can also force TLS1.2 by adding the following:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Comment: Hi @Manik tried putting this on global.asax under Application_Start didn't work for me. Any update on this?

Comment: Hi Vince, I've answered your question on GitHub :)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

I put this in global.asax Application_Start.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Answer (score 0):

Manik is right.
CreateSession fails at app start.
You must configure your app to use only TLS 1.2.
As of 6/6/19 the OpenTok .NET samples are broken unless you make this change.

OpenTok /.NET samples
https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-.NET-SDK

add to OpenTokService.cs:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Example: Create a demo account. make changes to the app.config for your API_KEY and API_SECRET
HelloWorld sample project will fail (at startup) with "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'" deep in the CreateSession Call.
in CreateSession -> Post -> DoRequest -> SendData ->SetRequestStream and then about 22 more stack levels down.