# OpenTok TokBox: REST API access forbidden when starting a live streaming broadcast

Tags: c#, .net, opentok, tokbox

Following the procedures outlined in the [SDK docs](https://tokbox.com/developer/rest/#start_broadcast).

Using .NET's WebRequest to make the API call.  StatusCode "Forbidden" being returned along with additional message "Invalid issuer format".

What I'm not sure about is how I'm supposed to generate the token for the call.  The instructions in the section I linked to simply say:

> REST API calls must be authenticated using a custom HTTP header — X-OPENTOK-AUTH — along with a JSON web token. Create the JWT token with the following claims.

This led me to believe I was to use the JWT library of my choice to create the token. So I did.  I used .NET's System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.

In the .NET section of the site, though, this appears:

> You can generate a token either by calling an OpenTokSDK.OpenTok instance's GenerateToken... method, or by calling a OpenTokSDK.Session instance's GenerateToken... method after creating it.

Was that what I was supposed to do?  Is that what's wrong?

I can include my code but no point if I've taken the wrong approach altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

There are two token concepts within the OpenTok API. One of the tokens is used to authenticate an [OpenTok Session](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Session.html) and the other is a JWT token used to authenticate each HTTP request you make from the server side.

It looks like the token that you're trying to create is used to interact with the [OpenTok REST API](https://tokbox.com/developer/rest/). Each request you make to the OpenTok REST API has to have a JWT token which is signed by your API Key and API Secret. The signing would look something like this:

```
var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>
  {
    { "iss", "12321312" }, // apiKey
    { "ist", "project" },
    { "iat", now }, // current time
    { "exp", expiry } // current time + 300 seconds
  };
```

You can use the [`GenerateJWT`](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-.NET-SDK/blob/master/OpenTok/Util/HttpClient.cs#L231) method in the [OpenTok .NET SDK](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-.NET-SDK) as reference. Alternatively, you can use the OpenTok .NET SDK to make the `StartBroadcast` request which would handle the JWT token creation for you.

Lastly, to authenticate an OpenTok Session you have to use one of the [OpenTok Server SDKs](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/server/). Please note that tokens used to authenticate OpenTok Sessions are not created by any library.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I decided to try the StartBroadcast route.  An exception is generated and the message returned is "{"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."}". I'm using the account apiKey and apiSecret when creating my OpenTok instance.  Is that correct?

Comment: Hmm, was the sessionId that you tried starting the broadcast for generated by the same apiKey and secret that you used to generate your OpenTok instance? Please also make sure that you're using TLS 1.1 or above. More info on the TLS item here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659216/opentok-createsession-error-with-request-submission/51659337#51659337

Comment: Thanks again.  No dice so far.  4.6.2 .net framework.  Have tried explicitly configuring TLS 1.1 and 1.2 in code.  Have verified that sessionId that I tried starting the broadcast for was generated by the same apiKey and secret that I used to generate the OpenTok instance.  I even carefully went through and repeated the process - generated a new project based session ID and token (Role=Publisher, Expiration Time=30 Days). Same result.  Using this same set of keys/tokens I am able to successfully publish/subscribe to multiple cameras and see the composite feed.  I just can't hit the API.

Comment: Robert, could you please file an issue on the .NET SDK repo and share your code? It'll be easier to debug and I'd to see this work for you!
https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-.NET-SDK/

Comment: My bad.  Was using my "account" key/secret combination and not my "project" combo when making my server side OpenTok instance.  So the answer is startBroadcast is a good .net option and use only project apiKey and secret.  Don't use the account level keys for this operation.  Thanks much for that.  Seems I can't get the stream to play though because my Wowza streaming server application requires authentication.  Does startBroadcast() have a mechanism for passing the stream authentication data?

Comment: Ah, glad you found it! Yes, you must use the project api key and secret for the main API functionality. The account api key and secret are there for creating/deleting projects programatically.

As for the wowza streaming, please file an issue on the .NET repo. I also recommend checking the broadcast application there to see the sample :)

Comment: Looks like I can modify my Wowza server to accept authentication via URL.  I'll have to go there for now in the interest of expediency (bit of a deadline).  Will revisit when more time.  But the essential question here was answered - use startBroadcast and use the project key/secret.  Thanks much.